# overlapping tags (e.g. ballooning, lighter-than-air)

Tags: discussion

There seem to be several sets of overlapping tags - are these useful?

For example

- [lighter-than-air](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lighter-than-air)

  - [ballooning](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ballooning)
  - but no [airship](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airship) or [zepppelin](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zepppelin) tags
- [unpowered](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unpowered)

  - [glider](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glider)

    - [hang-glider](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hang-glider)

so we get questions tagged

[unpowered](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unpowered) [ballooning](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ballooning) [lighter-than-air](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lighter-than-air).

is this desirable?

Answer (score 1):

> are these useful?

Could be, depending on the context.
You can always propose a [Tag synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).

> so we get questions tagged
> [unpowered](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unpowered)[ballooning](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ballooning)[lighter-than-air](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lighter-than-air)
>
> is this desirable?

Again, depends on the question, but I would say that having only the most appropriate tag for each question would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the tags have different purposes.

[lighter-than-air](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lighter-than-air) is a general tag that could be used for questions that would apply to **all** lighter than air aircraft and not specific to one of the aircraft categories.

The FAA categories would be balloon and airship.  It would be appropriate for both [balloon](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balloon) and [airship](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airship) to be created, **on an as-needed basis**.  We don't create tags preemptively just because they "might" be used down the road, so the fact that [airship](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airship) doesn't exist simply means that no questions have been asked that are specific to airships yet.

For a question that is about a specific aircraft, both tags could be included in order to help find the question.  For instance, if I am searching for all questions about lighter than air aircraft, I would want to see airships too.  This is part of the reason that we can provide up to five tags on the same question.

In short, I would say that yes, what you are seeing is desirable.